# Wordpress - show div id with template part if it matches page id otherwise dont

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Looking for a simple if/else statement in Wordpress to show a code that includes a template-part IF it's on page id's 30 and 40 but don't show it on any other page.

My Code:

```
<div id="tg-menu" class="tab-content">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/menus', 'lunch-menu',array('child_id' => $args['child_id'])); ?>
</div>
```

Also, this code would need to be targeted to the same ID's to show if they meet the 2 page id's otherwise don't show on any other pages.

```
<a href="#tg" target="_blank" class="button--gold btn-gold-x-sm shrink center-flex" style="margin-top: 30px">
        <span class="btn_text">Menu</span>
</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

us the [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function and use your Id's as the parameters

```
<?php if ( is_page(30) || is_page(40) ): ?>
    <div id="tg-menu" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/menus', 'lunch-menu', array('child_id' => $args['child_id'])); ?>
    </div>

    <a href="#tg" target="_blank" class="button--gold btn-gold-x-sm shrink center-flex" style="margin-top: 30px">
            <span class="btn_text">Menu</span>
    </a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work by wrapping it in this as well and it worked:


<?php
$page_id = get_the_ID();
if($page_id === 3112 || $page_id === 4897)
{
?> 

CODE HERE and then ending with:


<?php
}
?>